# Como puedo crear un id aleatorio en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Siempre he creado tablas con un `id` primario autoincrementado y no me ha dado problemas, pero lo que me interesa es tener un `id` más difícil de recordar y que no lleve un orden pero que no permita duplicados.

Tengo esto:

```
ID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Quiero esto:

```
ID: 234434, 32323, 03043, 232345, 33124, 66674
```

¿Cómo lo lograría desde el mismo `phpmyadmin` o cualquier otro método más eficiente?

Comment: Si quieres un valor único, no secuencial y "difícil de recordar" explora el tipo `GUID`.

Comment: `GUID` es un `Data Type` disponible en [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd354925.aspx), mientras que quien pregunta utiliza PHP y MySQL

Comment: Puedes codificar/decodificar el `id` para que aparentemente sea aleatorio tanto en MySQL como en PHP. Un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo en MySQL lo tienes aquí: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nayysvk7Doeub5CjsztZa3/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nayysvk7Doeub5CjsztZa3/0). Si quieres hacerlo portable entonces es mejor hacerlo en PHP. De esta manera no tienes que rehacer tu base de datos y el usuario no tiene por qué conocer el `id` real.

Answer (score 2):

En tu aplicación web puedes utilizar la función `uniqid()` de PHP, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    echo uniqid();
?>
```

Y de acuerdo a [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_uniqid.asp):

> The uniqid() function generates a unique ID based on the microtime (current time in microseconds).

La función `uniqid()` genera un ID único basado en el microtiempo (tiempo actual en microsegundos). Si deseas agregar mayor aleatoriedad puedes usar `more_entropy`, [aquí un enlace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) a la documentación oficial que puede ser de tu interés.

Otra opción es que utilices la función `UUID()` o también `UUID_SHORT()`, ambas disponibles en MySQL, aquí unos ejemplos simples:

```
mysql> SELECT UUID();
    -> '6ccd780c-baba-1026-9564-5b8c656024db'

mysql> SELECT UUID_SHORT();
    -> 92395783831158784
```

Para aprender más detalles de cómo generar ambas opciones, aquí la documentación:

- [UUID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)
- [UUID_SHORT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short)

Espero que te sirva.